# Splicing files fast in Python and getting their md5

Tags: python, file-io, md5

I'm trying to split up a file into smaller pieces of +/- 300 kilobytes a piece.
This is quite slow for a file of 300 megabytes (+/- 1000 pieces)

I'm not using any threading yet, I 'm not sure if that would make it run any faster

```
    cs = 1
    pieces = 1000

    # Open the file
    f = open(self.file, 'rb')
    result = {}

    while cs <= pieces:

        #Filename
        filename = str(cs).zfill(5) + '.split'

        # Generate temporary filename
        tfile = filename

        # Open the temporary file
        w = open(tfile, 'wb')

        # Read the first split
        tdata = f.read(maxsize)

        # Write the data
        w.write(tdata)

        # Close the file
        w.close()

        # Get the hash of this chunk
        result[filename] = self.__md5(tfile)

        cs += 1
```

This is the md5 function:

```
def __md5(self, f, block_size=2**20):

    f = open(f, 'rb')

    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    while True:
        data = f.read(block_size)
        if not data:
            break
        md5.update(data)
    return md5.hexdigest()
```

So is there any way to speed things up?

Comment: Would this problem be better solved by `split(1)`?

Comment: I'm not sure how much threading would help here, as MD5 is very fast, and you're probably I/O bound. You could easily try it though, as the blocks can be hashed independently. In that case I recommend using a thread for each core/CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the chunk, saving it to a temporary file, then reading the temporary file and computing its md5. That's unnecessary, though - you can compute the md5 while the chunk is still in memory. That means you won't have to open the temp file and read it, which should be faster.

Also I'd recommend a smaller blocksize - maybe 2^11 or 2^12.

Comment: Agreed on the tempfile, it is unnecessary and inefficient. But why a smaller blocksize? Using a large blocksize means that less time is spent in Python looping, at the only expense of somewhat more memory use.

Comment: ah maybe it's hard to have 1 mb of contiguous memory on demand? so the memory allocation might take a while, but it's easier with smaller blocks. just a random hunch though, i have no data to back it up